# Is it possible to screencast from an iOS device to a Chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast

Is it possible to screencast from an iOS device to a Chromecast?

We'd like to be able to screencast in the same way you can from an iOS device to an Apple TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting (mirroring) the entire screen of your iOS device to Chromecast is not possible. Apple TV uses an Apple proprietary technology called AirPlay for screen mirroring.

Casting is only available for compatible apps which have added support for Chromecast. In compatible apps, you will be shown a rectangular button with little wireless icon in the bottom left corner, as shown in the image below:

[image] [image]

Comment: Are there no VNC apps for IOS?

Comment: @WGroleau There are many VNC apps for iOS but only client apps and not server apps.

Comment: Perhaps I should make one.  Nah, I should stay retired.  :-)

Comment: Are you talking about making a VNC server app for iOS? It may not be feasible to create such an app.

Comment: Apple would probably refuse to put it in the store, but if it were available open source, anyone with developer tools could compile it and put it on their own device.

Comment: I agree it may not get approved. It may require some workarounds to keep it running in the background. Also, not sure if there's a way to capture the frame-buffer of an iOS device to send over VNC protocol (at least in non-jailbroken devices).